# Как выдать/отнять привилегии на инвалидное представление(view)?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

У меня есть инвалидное представление. Я пытаюсь на него выдать\отнять привилегии:

```
grant select on my_view to my_user;
```

получаю ошибку:

> ORA-04063: view 'MY_VIEW" has errors

Можно ли как то исхитриться и работать с привилегиями инвалидных view не исправляя/заменяя саму view ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На asktom [пишут](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9534169800346780746), что нельзя. Предлагают следующую альтернативу:

- сохранить код view с ошибками;
- заменить view на корректное;
- выдать/забрать права;
- выполнить `CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW` с опцией `FORCE`, чтобы вернуть код с ошибками.